# array of objects for an html5 canvas nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, adobe, createjs

I have a html5 Canvas animation that I am doing on Adobe Animate and tweaking with some code.

I have a portion on the animation that will be like a combobox with all the links to navigate through the different frames. The thing is, I don't want to be creating a bunch of EventListener to many buttons because from experience I know that doesn't work so well. So I am trying to think of a more creative solution. This is my idea.

1. Create an array that will contain all the buttons.
2. Assing a variable for each target frame.
3. Create a for loop with a function inside that assigns the listener to the selected button and then points it to the desired frame (variable)

This is what I have got so far, (not much)

```
    var combobox = [this.btncasco , this.btnbanyera , this.btnLumbrera , this.btnproapopa, this.btnestriborbabor ];


for (var i=0; i<combobox.length; i++) {
var clipcasco = gotoAndStop(0);
var clipbanyera = gotoAndStop(2);
var cliplumbera = gotoAndStop(4);
var clipproapoa = gotoAndStop(6);
var clipestriborbabor = gotoAndStop(8);


    }
```

Would that be feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are just assigning the result of gotoAndStop (with no scope, so likely you're getting an error in the console)

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<combobox.length; i++) {

  // This is kind of complex, but if you just reference "i" in your callback
  // It will always be combobox.length, since it references the value of i
  // after the for loop completes variable.
  // So just store a new reference on your button to make it easy
  combobox[i].index = i*2; // x2 lines up with your code 0,2,4,etc.

  // Add a listener to the button
  combobox[i].on("click", function(event) {
    // Use event.target instead of combobox[i] for the same reason as above.
    event.target.gotoAndStop(event.target.index);
  }

}
```

You might have the same problem as your other StackOverflow post where the button is undefined (check the console). There is actually a bug in Animate export right now where children of a clip are not *immediately* available. To get around this, you can call `this.gotoAndStop(0);` at the start to force it to update the children.